# Counting the number of elements in an array - C

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to count the number of elements in an array using C. I tried out the following code. But it just returns 83 every time I run the program. What I mean by to count the number of elements is that I need to know the number of elements that we have entered and not the size of the array.

```
 #include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
main(){

int a[100], j = 0, i;

a[0] = '0';
a[1] = '1';
a[2] = '2';
a[3] = '3';
a[4] = '4';
a[5] = '5';

for(i=0; i<100; i++){

       if(a[i] == '\0'){

       }        
        else
            j = j + 1;          
}

printf("%d", j);

system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Before you go any further with C, please read a good book.

Comment: @dreamlax sorry that was the wrong piece of code which I copied. please check it out now

Comment: Much better! But still not quite correct... because you only set the values of the first 6 elements, the rest of them have indeterminate values and you cannot rely on uninitialised values like you are in the loop. Once `i` goes past 5, it starts reading uninitialised values from the array, and this is bad.

Comment: Now I created a for loop before I assign the values which clears all the default values in the array and then I run this code. Works perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: So you run a loop to clear memory, and then a second loop that you show above? If so, that's unnecessary and inefficient. And also quite likely to confuse anyone else looking at the code. Consider just tagging on the correct delimiter to the end of your array instead.

Comment: The question is bad-posed. You need to specify if you initialized the array, with what elemets you need to fill it, what is the max limit of elements you expect to fill, etc.

Comment: @Srivathsan In my answer you only have to make a single change to your present code and you won't need a second whole loop. Give it a try and see if that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the OP amended his code, here is a more correct reply:
This code works 'by chance', since you didn't initialize the array previously.
It's just 'luck', that somewhere in there, the value 0 comes up.

The declaration of an array does NOT zero it.
Use:

```
memset(a, 0, 100);
```

For that. That way, the first 'not overwritten' byte will return '0'.
Reference: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/memset/

Alternatively, you have to set the 'delimited' manually by adding a[x] = 0;

Now, I know you specifically asked for a 'C' solution, but if you would like to consider using a C++-Compiler, I suggest looking at the stl of C++.
Here's a link to get you started: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/

It's initialized as:

```
list<char>List;
List.push_back(1);
List.push_back(2);
List.push_back('a');

int j = List.size();   //Returns '3'
```

Comment: sorry that was the wrong piece of code which I copied. please check it out now

Comment: Ah I see. I amended my reply accordingly.

Comment: Since the OP tagged with C and is using C headers, C++ is probably not the correct solution here?

Comment: @JoshPetitt Ah right, he did. Well, the 'memset' is the actual answer. The STL is only a 'suggestion for a different take on the matter'. But thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

Arrays in C are a **fixed size**.  They do not expand.  Your `array` has two entries; writing to `array[2]`, `array[3]`, etc. invokes **undefined behaviour**.  In other words, it's invalid code.

If you want to be able to insert an arbitrary number of elements, you will need to use dynamically-allocated memory, manually track how many elements you've inserted, and use `realloc` when you need to resize.

Comment: sorry that was the wrong piece of code which I copied. please check it out now

Answer (score 1):

do this instead:

```
main(){

  int a[100] = {0};
  int j = 0;
  int i = 0;

  // other stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update based on new code:**

In general, you will need a way to identify the end of your array in order to do a correct count. For strings the `'\0'` is used generally. For other data types you have to come up with your own value to check.

For your specific code example above:

You need to insert a `\0` yourself into your array in the last position so that your count will work. (When you create a string like "hello", the `'\0'` gets automatically put in for you at the end of the string, but not if you create a string character by character).

Alternatively, check for the character `'5'` to find the end of your current array of characters.

Also, you should `break` out of the loop once you found the last character, otherwise you are going past the end of the array and will most likely crash (again, if you don't it's sheer luck). I.e., something like:

```
   if(a[i] == '\0'){
      break;
   }
```

will work if you do:

```
   a[6] = '\0';
```

before.

Since C doesn't check array bounds, it might appear that with your current code you *seemingly* get away with this, but it's *sheer luck* that the program doesn't crash and may change from run to run. In other words, this is **undefined** behavior.

Finally, you can of course also use `strlen()` if you are dealing with strings.